# Extras vs Backports

Tags: apt, software-sources

What are `extras` in the context of software sources ? How do they differ from backports ?

[ This is only to let me pass the minimum length constraint ]

Answer (score 0):

Extras include 3rd-party software that is available for this version of Ubuntu. Packages here aren't in the core Ubuntu repo, but are instead in a different repo (located at http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu).

Currently, there's only one package for Utopic (something related to PPAs), and no packages for Vivid, which might mean that this is being closed down.

Backports, on the other hand, is the process of bringing newer versions of programs in a later Ubuntu release back to the current Ubuntu release. This is managed by Ubuntu itself, and people can request a backport of some package by following [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports) process. Backports *are* in the core Ubuntu repo, in the `-backports` section of the repo.

Comment: so extras is essentially a more controller form of launchpad or am I missing something ?

Comment: Extras isn't managed in any way from Launchpad (as far as I know). It's a place for third-party developers to distribute the latest version of their software to users. That being said, there's only one package for Utopic, and no packages for Vivid, which makes me think this is being phased out.